# AWS SQS Client Acknowledge mode in .NET CORE SDK

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-net

My intention is to have messages be deleted automatically from AWS SQS by not calling delete massage after receiving it. How do i set "acknowledge mode" in .net core?

I use `services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();` to create my SQS client.

There is an example for Java: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html#using-client-acknowledge-mode](http://acknowledge%20mode%20in%20Java)

Can same be done for .NET Core SDK? Thanks.

Comment: That is using the AWS JMS (Java Messaging Service) interface.  It is a layer on top of SQS that does the polling and message acknowledgement for you.  "Normal" Java implementations still do the message deletion in code.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks. I didnt know that.